# How to remove Docker.Service from startup

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, containers, docker-for-windows

Every time i start my computer, the Docker.Service service is loaded into my memory.

System: Windows 10 Pro 1903, Docker 2.0.0.3

I tried to avoid this by:

- Disabling docker in the task manager startup tab
- Disabling it in the Docker for Desktop itself
- Removing all docker related entries from the Run / RunService folders in the registry

Still, Docker.Service appears in my task manager after restarting my computer.
How can i prevent my computer to load Docker.Service on startup?

Comment: Try "Autoruns" tool from sysinternals

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me this was annoying too and i have solved this by simply unticking the check box `Start Docker Desktop when you login`. This setting can be found if you right click on the whale in the tray and then go to `settings > general`.
If i now want to use Docker i have to manually start it.

You can also go to windows services `WIN + R > services.msc` and there you can manipulate the `Docker Desktop Service`. If it is configured to start automatically you can set this to `manual` in the properties of the service.

Comment: Thanks! The service.msc thingy did it for me. I completly forgot about this since I was messing around with the registry. You earned the bounty.